# How to move catrgory labels under time labels in a distill blog

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, r-distill

The distill package in r allows to add categories/labels for posts and they will show in the post listing page.

But their default position is under the title of each post, shown as below:

[default position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBtoT.png)

But I want to move these category labels under the time labels. It should look like:
[expeted position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWJwq.png)

What codes I should add to the custom css file? I didn't find any source code of distill blogs with that style.

Thank you in advance if you could read my question and reply.

Comment: I find one website with expected style: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/11424/
But I can't find its github page or css file.

Comment: The github page is here: https://github.com/jjallaire/reproducible-finance-with-r

There is not custom css files, so I think this category label style might be in an older distill version.